# change color of text jquery (only one div at a time)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple "links" (buttons) that load pictures based on which link is clicked. I want to change the color of the text of the current link from gray to black, but when a different link is pressed I would like the color to revert back to gray, but am not sure how to do this because right now I end up making all the links turn from gray to black?

Below is an example of 2 of the links (out of 20).

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".NYC_link").click(function() {
            $(".NYC_link a").css('color', 'black');
        });
        $( ".LA_link" ).click(function() {
            $(".LA_link a").css('color', 'black');
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="gallerynames">
    <div class="NYC_link">
        <a>NYC Apartment</a>
    </div>
    <div class="LA_link">
        <a>LA Home</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your html?

Comment: I don't want all the links to change to black, only one at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a separate class for each of link in order to operate with them. Create the single class for all of them:

```
<a href="#" class="cityLink NYC_link">NYC</a>
<a href="#" class="cityLink LA_link">LA</a>

<a href="#" class="cityLink LV_link">20 more cities go here...</a>
```

Then, you can use the following script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".cityLink").click(function() {
            $(".cityLink").css('color', 'gray');
            $(this).css('color', 'black');
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can use `this` to get the clicked item in order to change the CSS color.

So, if someone clicks the link - you can color all other links of this class to gray - then, you can color the clicked link into black. This way you will have only the last clicked link colored black.

Anyway, changing the color this way is a **really bad approach**.

You might want to create a class "active" and describe it this way:

```
.cityLink {
    color: gray;
}

.cityLink.active {
    color: black;
}
```

Then, you can do the same thing with this script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".cityLink").click(function() {
            $(".cityLink").removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Check [this JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qn0g1w7m/1/) out.

Comment: there are more than 20 links...this only works if there are actually 2

Comment: @Max You want to say that you have a separate class for each of link? Please, provide your HTML. Check my update.

Comment: @Max Look at this now: http://jsfiddle.net/Lhynm5ew/2/. It works fine with your HTML code. However, it is not a good approach - read my article for more information.

Comment: the only thing I'm confused about is where 'active' is declared

Comment: @Max It is not declared anywhere - you can declare it yourself in your CSS file. You can name it `coloredBlack` or whatever you want :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `this` in *context* of selector, [jQuery( selector [, context ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) to access the `a` in current `NYC_link` alternatively you can use `$(this).find("a")`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".NYC_link").click(function() {
         $("a", this).css('color', 'black');
     });
     $( ".LA_link" ).click(function() {
         $(this).find("a").css('color', 'black');
     });
});
```